# Form validation in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want validate a form consists of user details. Besides the basic validation for non-empty checking i also want to check whether username/email exits in DB. For email field i want to check for non-empty, format and lastly its availability in the DB. And the error message for email should be alternative and username also.

here i attempted so far -

```
app.post('/user-add', checkAuth, function(req,res){

    req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty(); 
    req.checkBody('first_name', 'First Name is required').notEmpty(); 
    req.checkBody('last_name', 'Last Name is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Valid Email is required').isEmail();
});
```

So how to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: you have done the basic checks and the code is fine, what you can do is further modularize it. But I think you need the code to check that the username/email is already present in the DB or not, am I right?

Comment: @nivesh yes indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use validator. it's a node package . Excellent and very simple to use .Try it once . You can find it here [validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator)

Server-side usage

Install the library with `npm install validator`

```
    var validator = require('validator');

    validator.isEmail('foo@bar.com'); //=> true
```

ES6

```
    import validator from 'validator';
```

Or, import only a subset of the library:

```
    import isEmail from 'validator/lib/isEmail';
```

Client-side usage
   The library can be loaded either as a standalone script, or through an AMD-compatible loader

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="validator.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      validator.isEmail('foo@bar.com'); //=> true
//can use this syntax for checking availability of fields in body  
if( req.body.email == undefined ||  req.body.email == '' ||  req.body.email == null)
            {
                // do something such as throw error
            }
// check for valid or invalid attribute
            if(!validator.isEmail(req.body.email)){
               // do something such as throw error
            }
  </script>
```

Comment: Will be great if you provide some examples in using this library specific to the question. Thanks.

Comment: does this support custom validation like availability of usename/email ? I am currently using "express-validator".

Comment: @ghaiklor thanks for the reply. I am using "express-validator" as module. A small portion of code i have already included with this post.

Comment: @virendra thanks for the reply. But in your example code you did not mention username / email for availability checking. Can you please post on this?

Comment: @parthachowdhury i am using such kind of syntax .. please check the updated updated answer